# DNS через VirtualBox

Tags: windows, dns, virtualbox

Возможно ли через VirtualBox настроить DNS? Или может плагин какой? На роутере нет такой возможности. В Windows конечно можно в хостах прописать например site.loc 192.168.1.105, а вот с телефона зайти site.loc то естественно не найдет.

Comment: на любую машину поставьте bind и настройте его так, как Вам нужно. В настройках роутера пропишите в качестве первого dns эту машину. Вторую запись днс возьмите с первой. И готово.

Comment: Спасибо, ну тогда так попробую, думал, чтоб не ставить лишнее ПО. Попробую — отпишусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ставите любой DNS-server на машину/VPS
2. Указываете свои A/AAAA/SRV-записи.
3. На роутере в настройках dhcp - указываете использовать в качестве dns ip-адрес вашей машины/VPS

P.S.: Чтобы долго не возится - [это решение](https://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/), кажется подходит для вашей задачи.

P.S.S: Также можно посмотреть в сторону прокси-сервера. Многие устройства их поддерживают.

Comment: Спасибо, поискал, как настраивать Acrylic, наверное старые статьи, папки Config нет в папке с установленной программой, есть AcrylicHosts.txt, добавил попробовать `74.125.232.229 vk.com` перезапустил Acrylic, установил в качестве DNS (пока в настройках беспроводного подкл. на ноутбуке) сначала 127.0.0.1, потом ip ноутбука, где установлен Acrylic - нет доступа к интернету.

Comment: 1. В Acrylic указан глобальный DNS

2. Что говорит nslookup google.com?

3. А 53 порт открыт?

4. На каком адресе слушает Acrylic?

Comment: Все, на Ubuntu 16.04 настроил :-) Может кому пригодится, делал по этой статье: http://mhelp.kz/nastroyka-dns-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Можно еще попробовать openwrt/Gentoo. Будет занимать ресурсов не больше чем нужно.

Comment: Я работал только с Debian/Ubuntu, пока и этому рад :-) Интересно, можно ли добавить прокси... или ставить nginx, создать хост и перенаправлять все запросы на какой-то ip?

Comment: Можно и то и другое, и обратный прокси с подменой контента, но подробнее смогу объяснить в другом вопросе... ;)